# Weird looking grid CSS

Tags: html, css, grid

I am trying to make a grid of images with captions. I am using simple CSS to create the grid.

CSS:

```
.float{float:left;padding:20;}
.float img{ width:80px; height:100px; padding:0;}
.float p {text-align:center; margin-top:0;width:100px;}
```

Then printing out several divs all using this same format:

```
<div class="float">
<img src="noimage.jpeg"></img>
<p>Movie Title</p>
</div>
```

The problem is the caption (Movie title in this case) is invariably long and sometimes spans multiple lines and I get a grid that looks like this:

[image]

Is there something I can change in the CSS to keep the images in line?

Comment: Can you use Table structure ?

Comment: I could but this way seems simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mention `text-align:center; height:180px;` in `.float` class

```
.float{float:left;padding:20; text-align:center; height:180px;}
```

I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: All these answers work well, but this one is the simplest that does exactly what I want. Thanks Dude.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the margins to 0 for ".float p"

.float p {.float p {text-align:center; width:100px; **margin:0 0 0 0;**}

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most beautiful solution to this problem, but this should stop the rows from beeing inconsistent. Perhaps you need to apply a bigger margin-bottom or padding-bottom, if the caption gets to long.

```
.float {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    padding:20px 20px 45px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.float p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 105px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 80px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each row of 5 elements in a div, and give it a class of `clearfix`, in your CSS add:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```